# Checar se radio button está selecionado

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Não estou conseguindo verificar a seguinte condição:

```js
$("#calculo").click(function() {
  if ($("#opcao2").cheked()) {
    $("#segundoConteudo").css("display", "none")
  }
})
```

```css
.labelFake {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p><span class="labelFake">Opções:</span>
  <label>Opção 1</label>
  <input type="radio" name="perfilCliente" id="opcao1">
  <label>Opção 2</label>
  <input type="radio" name="perfilCliente" id="opcao2">
</p>
<div id="segundoConteudo">
  <p><span class="labelFake">List Drop Down:</span>
    <select>
      <option>Opção 1</option>
      <option>Opção 2</option>
    </select>
  </p>
  <p><span class="labekFake">Selecione o produto:</span>
    <select class="prods">
      <option>Produto...</option>
    </select>
  </p>
  <button id="calculo">Calcular</button>
</div>
```

Resumindo: quero que quando a `#opcao2` estiver selecionada, a div "segundo conteudo" não apareça.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O correto é usar [prop](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-check-uncheck-a-checkbox-input-or-radio-button/):

```
$("elem").prop("checked");
```

Ao invés de:

```
$("#opcao2").cheked()
```

```js
$("#calculo").click(function() {
  if ($("#opcao2").prop("checked")) {
    $("#segundoConteudo").css("display", "none")
  }
})
```

```css
.labelFake {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><span class="labelFake">Opções:</span>
  <label>Opção 1</label>
  <input type="radio" name="perfilCliente" id="opcao1">
  <label>Opção 2</label>
  <input type="radio" name="perfilCliente" id="opcao2">
</p>
<div id="segundoConteudo">
  <p><span class="labelFake">List Drop Down:</span>
    <select>
      <option>Opção 1</option>
      <option>Opção 2</option>
    </select>
  </p>
  <p><span class="labekFake">Selecione o produto:</span>
    <select class="prods">
      <option>Produto...</option>
    </select>
  </p>
  <button id="calculo">Calcular</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Yay! Funcionou Lucas, realmente estava usando o comando errado, obrigado!